# create a Season job (a job with once schedule in 3 month)

Tags: sql-server, database, jobs

we have an archive process for 6 databases and we take a backup from each database and move to tape, In the following, I restore the same raw database, we must do this exactly at the end of the session but sometimes we forgot to do that, I want to create a job to remind me each 3 months with email, thank you.

it's better to take a log of this process into a table.

Comment: What's the question exactly? And have you considered SQL Agent?

Comment: i want to create a job to be run once in every 3 month

Comment: Put this as a recurring event in whatever calendar system you use. No need for anything SQL Server specific here.

Comment: I understand that's what you want but what is the question? Have you tried it? What were your results? Did you get an error, some other problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-schedule-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: yes, i attending to create a job but job schedule nothing has more than 1 month and i need to schedule once in the end of season, that is my problem.

Comment: Just do 122 days?

Comment: realy ? is it ok ?